# integerate dynamic data with google map

Tags: php, google-maps, codeigniter-2

DEMO Link: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=0e03WevMN4fT8geoxoGIBQ&gws_rd=ssl#rlla=0&hotel_dates=2017-06-23,2017-06-24&q=hotels+in+chandigarh&rflfq=1&rlha=1&rllag=30725477,76784980,2808&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u2000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u4000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u6000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u10000!3sINR!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!3sEAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6&rlfi=hd:2017-06-23,2017-06-24;si:10105726115128781649,CKi6iLGRp7mF6gESCjIwMTctMDYtMjMYASIKEAEYACB0MMz7FioTCKG8kt_bq9QCFcYmaAodVf4NlA,2;mv:!1m3!1d129726.33931459839!2d77.17302228320318!3d30.749590474637333!3m2!1i946!2i227!4f13.1;tbs:lf_hd:-1,lf_ho:2,lrf:!2m7!1e17!4m2!17m1!1e3!4m2!17m1!1e8!2m21!1e7!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u2000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u4000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u6000!3sINR!4m4!7m3!1m1!1u10000!3sINR!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e4!3sEAE,lf:1,lf_ui:6 . I am working on codeigniter. I want to to implement the same functionality as the demo. I also have dynamic data of hotels, so onmouseover I want to implement same. CAn anybody help me out ?

Comment: http://www.elluminati.in/how-to-create-google-map-demo-in-codeigniter/ .. Check This

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library :

http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/

It should be helpful for you.